# PHP: Can't insert more than one record into some of the MySQL table

Tags: php, mysqli, relational-database

I am having problem with my web-based CRM software project, where I can manage a person's job, contact information and company information. The first input works as intended, but starting from the second input, there are no new records inserted into `job` and `company` table.

```
<?php
  require_once '../conn.php';


//defining variables...



if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){


  //validation of input


}

  if(empty($err_first_name) && empty($err_last_name) && empty($err_media_type) && empty($err_priority)){


    mysqli_autocommit($conn, FALSE);

    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO person (first_name, last_name, media_type, magazine_sub, newsletter_sub, birthday, priority, remark, tel, mobile, fax, email, wechat)
             VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

        if ($stmt1 = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql1) or die(mysqli_error($conn))) {
          mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt1, 'sssiissssssss', $param_first_name, $param_last_name, $param_media_type, $param_magazine_sub, $param_newsletter_sub, $param_birthday, $param_priority, $param_remark, $param_tel, $param_mobile, $param_fax, $param_email, $param_wechat);

          $param_first_name = $first_name;
          $param_last_name = $last_name;
          $param_media_type = $media_type;
          $param_magazine_sub = $magazine_sub;
          $param_newsletter_sub = $newsletter_sub;
          $param_birthday = $birthday;
          $param_priority = $priority;
          $param_remark = $remark;
          $param_tel = $tel;
          $param_mobile = $mobile;
          $param_fax = $fax;
          $param_email = $email;
          $param_wechat = $wechat;
        }
          mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt1);
          $person_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
          mysqli_stmt_close($stmt1);



    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO address (type, street, city, state, zip, country)
             VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

        if ($stmt2 = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql2) or die(mysqli_error($conn))) {
          mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt2, 'ssssss', $param_address_type, $param_street, $param_city, $param_state, $param_zip, $param_country);

          $param_address_type = $address_type;
          $param_street = $street;
          $param_city = $city;
          $param_state = $state;
          $param_zip = $zip;
          $param_country = $country;
        }

        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2);
        $address_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt2);



  $sql3 = "INSERT INTO company (name_de)
           VALUES (?)";
      if ($stmt3 = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql3) or die(mysqli_error($conn))){
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt4, 's', $param_name_de);

        $param_name_de = $name_de;
      }

      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt3);
      $company_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
      mysqli_stmt_close($stmt3);


  $sql4 = "INSERT INTO job (person_id, company_id, department, position)
           VALUES ($person_id, $company_id, ?, ?)";
      if ($stmt4 = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql4) or die(mysqli_error($conn))){
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt4, 'ss', $param_dep, $param_pos);

        $param_dep = $department;
        $param_pos = $position;
      }

      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt4);
      mysqli_stmt_close($stmt4);

  $sql5 = "INSERT INTO person_address (person_id, address_id)
           VALUES ($person_id, $address_id)";

  mysqli_query($conn, $sql5);

  header("location: person.php");

  }
  mysqli_commit($conn);
  mysqli_close($conn);

}

 ?>


/*HTML-Form*/
```

If it helps, here is the relational schema of the database:

[image]

---

Table definition of affected table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `chkdcrm`.`job` (
  `job_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `person_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `company_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `department` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `position` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`job_id`, `company_id`, `person_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `job_person_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`person_id`)
    REFERENCES `chkdtest`.`person` (`person_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `company_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`)
    REFERENCES `chkdtest`.`company` (`company_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `chkdcrm`.`company` (
  `company_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name_de` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  `website` VARCHAR(255) NULL UNIQUE,
  `c_tel` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  `c_email` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  `service_region` ENUM('EU', 'Western Europe', 'Germany and German-speaking region', 'Others') NOT NULL,
  `registration_nr` VARCHAR(15) NULL UNIQUE,
  `c_remark` TEXT NULL,
  `date_added` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  `member_type` ENUM('board', 'counsil', 'class a', 'class b', 'automotive counsil', 'support', 'none') NOT NULL,
  `industry` ENUM(//blablabla) NOT NULL,
  `parent_company` INT(11) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`company_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `parent_company`
    FOREIGN KEY (`parent_company`)
    REFERENCES `chkdtest`.`company` (`company_id`)
    ON DELETE SET NULL)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: You've said, nothing happens after `$sql2`? Have you tried debugging the `mysqli_smtm_execute` functions? They return `false` on failure and `true´ on success: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php

Comment: @Spingolini Thanks for the tip, I'll look into it.

Comment: it sounds like you have a unique index on your foreign key therefore cant insert the same data again

Comment: @JamesKirkby I checked and this is not the case. I did not index anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed all the `UNIQUE` constraints from the `company` table, since input from the form only inserts `name_de` into the table, and all other unique field are set to NULL by default, by the second entry there would be 2 NULL field, which conflicts with the UNIQUE constraint.

But I'm not sure how much removing the UNIQUE constraint would affect the integrity of my database.

Comment: you must be inserting more than just name_de as you have multiple 'not null' on multiple columns so you are either inserting none unique data, or your  null unique columns are not having data put in them which means it will default to null which is not unique for subsequant inserts. either way as i stated before it is due to unique index on columns.